# Looping through a list when building group_vars in ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2

I'm rather new to ansible and would like to deploy prometheus-grok-exporter (via ansible-grok-exporter role) with a specific configuration for all my nodes that run the cacti application.

My inventory is like this:

```
cacti_first ansible_host=192.168.50.50
cacti_second ansible_host=192.168.50.51

[group__cacti]
cacti_first
cacti_second
```

Inside `group_vars/group__cacti` I want to add something like this:

```
---
prometheus_grok_services_template:
  - name: cacti_metrics
    config_version: 3
    input:
        type: file
        paths: 
        {% for cacti_dir in cacti_path %}
        - "{{cacti_dir}}/log/cacti.log"
        {% endfor %}
        readall: false
        extaConfigContinuesFromHere: true
```

And I have host config like this:
`host_vars/cacti_first`:

```
---
cacti_path:
 - /usr/share/cacti
prometheus_grok_services:
  - prometheus_grok_services_template
```

`host_vars/cacti_second`:

```
---
cacti_path:
 - /usr/share/cacti
 - /usr/share/cacti2
prometheus_grok_services:
  - prometheus_grok_services_template
```

Inside the playbook I do a loop for `prometheus_grok_services` and use the yaml data to provision the service.

Now - this works as long as I don't try to use a loop inside `group_vars/group__cacti`. ansible-inventory reports that:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i hosts --list cacti_second
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found character that cannot start any token

The error appears to be in '/home/bastion/ansible-playbooks/group_vars/group__cacti': line 8, column 10, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        paths:
        {% for cacti_dir in cacti_path %}
         ^ here
```

So, I'd like to ask - is it allowed to do jinja loops to build yaml for group vars? Is it a syntax error on my end? How am I supposed to template it?

I'd like to avoid moving the block to host vars (which I know works), mostly because it's a large piece of code (about 2KB of yaml config) and it's not as elegant as using group vars.

Thanks!

Comment: indentation for the list items for `cacti_path`  is incorrect. move that `- /usr/share/cacti` and `- /usr/share/cacti2` to one space left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the group_vars. For example

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/group__cacti
---
prometheus_grok_services_template:
  - name: cacti_metrics
    config_version: 3
    input:
        type: file
        paths: "{{ paths_str|from_yaml }}"
        readall: false
        extaConfigContinuesFromHere: true
paths_str: |
  {% for cacti_dir in cacti_path %}
  - {{ cacti_dir }}/log/cacti.log
  {% endfor %}
```

Then, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: group__cacti
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', item) }}"
      loop: "{{ prometheus_grok_services }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [cacti_first] => (item=prometheus_grok_services_template) =>
  msg:
  - config_version: 3
    input:
      extaConfigContinuesFromHere: true
      paths:
      - /usr/share/cacti/log/cacti.log
      readall: false
      type: file
    name: cacti_metrics
ok: [cacti_second] => (item=prometheus_grok_services_template) => 
  msg:
  - config_version: 3
    input:
      extaConfigContinuesFromHere: true
      paths:
      - /usr/share/cacti/log/cacti.log
      - /usr/share/cacti2/log/cacti.log
      readall: false
      type: file
    name: cacti_metrics
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know you could "import" inline yaml code. I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this kind of for loop in a variables file or a playbook - it only works in template files.  To acheive what you're after, you can use product filters, as described https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products

In your example, you would have:

```yaml
---
prometheus_grok_services_template:
  - name: cacti_metrics
    config_version: 3
    input:
        type: file
        paths: "{{ cacti_path | product(['/log/cacti.log']) | map('join') | list }}"
        readall: false
        extaConfigContinuesFromHere: true
```

Comment: `You can't use this kind of for loop in a variables file or a playbook - it only works in template files` <= **this statement is wrong**. Although not always a good practice and not encouraged, it is totally possible (and I can give you quite a few "exception is not the rule" examples where it was hard to avoid them). The problem here is only syntax and correct quoting/scalar block marking. See Vladimir's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I managed to bypass the problem by passing a list of precomputed paths, but your solution is more elegant!